# Setting AL_GAIN to 0 works on iPhone6, not iPad PRO?

Tags: audio, openal, multiplatform

To silence my game when returning to the menu, I call this code:

```
alListenerf( AL_GAIN, gain );
```

This works just fine on Linux: the game goes silent.

When I run on iPad PRO, the sounds are still played, and volume is not affected at all.

Is AL_GAIN optionally implemented in the spec or something?

```
Using OpenAL device 'Default Audio Device'
Using ALUT 1.1
AL_VENDOR Apple Inc.
AL_RENDERER Software
AL_VERSION 1.1
```

This is on the latest iPad PRO model, by the way.

**Whoa! the plot thickens...** setting gain on iPhone6 works, on iPad PRO it does not. The same binary.

It is probably an iOS version thing. The iPad is on iOS 11.4 and the phone is on iOS 10.3.3

Answer (score 1):

in linux and other platforms setting the volume to 0 works but for the ios13 bug as in the iPad pro change the volume to 0.001f and it should bypass Apple's bug.